# GatoIcon.py automatically generated <?> from images via perl?

Tags: python, perl

```
yellow = """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=
"""

def Init():
    import GatoUtil
    imageCache = GatoUtil.ImageCache() # singleton
    imageCache.AddImage("Icons/yellow.gif",yellow)
```

I ran across this open-source python graph module and this file intrigued me.
Now it says the above file is `NOTE:   Automatically created by mkGatoIcons.pl`

I wanted to take a look at this perl script but it was not available and I am wondering how would I go about making my own perl script that generates the above?

is the perl script taking some images and translate into binaries or some sort?

NOTE: Gato (Graph Animation Toolbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked this for certain, but that's probably just a base64 encoded gif file. If so, it'd be generated with something like:

```
use MIME::Base64;

open(my $gif, '<:raw', 'yellow.gif');
local $/;
say encode_base64(<$gif>);
```

Edit: Yep:

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -E "open (my $output, '>:raw', $ARGV[0]); print $output decode_base64('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')" yellow.gif
```